# RxSwift like Actions for Android

Tags: android, ios, rx-java, rx-swift, rx-kotlin

I was first introduced to reactive programming with **ReactiveCocoa** several years ago. In there they had the notion on `RACCommand`s, which was carried over to **RxSwift** with the extension library **[Action](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action)**.

As stated on their GitHub page:

> An action is a way to say "hey, later I'll need you to subscribe to this thing."
>
> Actions accept a `workFactory`: a closure that takes some input and produces an observable. When `execute()` is called, it passes its parameter to this closure and subscribes to the work.
>
> - Can only be executed while "enabled" (true if unspecified).
> - Only execute one thing at a time.
> - Aggregates next/error events across individual executions.

In my experience it is an absolutely *indispensable* tool in the reactive programming toolbox when doing robust, reactive iOS development.

---

Now we would like to carry this over to **Android** app as well. But after countless hours of research I have not been able to find a corresponding component for either **RxJava** or **RxKotlin**.

The implementation in Swift is relatively straight forward, so we *could* just port it, but I'd first like to hear if:

1. This really does not exists, and if so
2. Is there an Android specific reason for this to not exist, i.e. a reason **not** to port it

Comment: I don't fully understand the linked libraries (I'm not an iOS/Swift dev) but it somewhat resembles to the [RxJavaComputationExpressions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaComputationExpressions) ([in v2](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#asynchronous-jumpstarting-a-sequence)) or Android's own `AsyncTask`. I'd suggest rethinking what you want to achieve and use straightforward RxJava constructs though.

Comment: Closest thing https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Comment: Are you thinking of a Java [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)? You include some work to be done inside the `call` method and you can submit it to an `Executor` to get a `Future` or make it into an Observable with `Observable.fromCallable()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up porting the iOS version ourselves.

It's open source and can be found here: **https://github.com/tonsser/kaction**